# TDS build failing in azure pipeline but its working fine locally

Tags: sitecore-client, upgrade

I have upgraded sitecore 9.3 to 10.3 and its locally build working fine in locally. When i try to build solution in azure getting below error.

```
Bundling items from project 'F:\BuildAgent\agent\_work\1\s\Feature.Labels.TDS.Templates\Feature.Labels.TDS.Templates.scproj' into package
2023-08-30T17:35:02.7231841Z   Exception The type initializer for 'Sitecore.DependencyInjection.DefaultSitecoreServicesConfigurator' threw an exception.(System.TypeInitializationException):
2023-08-30T17:35:02.7233157Z      at Sitecore.DependencyInjection.DefaultSitecoreServicesConfigurator.Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
2023-08-30T17:35:02.7233835Z      at Sitecore.DependencyInjection.BaseServicesConfiguratorFactory.Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
2023-08-30T17:35:02.7234235Z      at Sitecore.DependencyInjection.BaseServiceProviderBuilder.ConfigureServiceCollection()
2023-08-30T17:35:02.7234748Z      at Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator.ConfigureServiceProvider()
2023-08-30T17:35:02.7235272Z      at Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator.get_ServiceProvider()
2023-08-30T17:35:02.7235576Z      at Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.c.b__354_0()
2023-08-30T17:35:02.7235844Z      at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
2023-08-30T17:35:02.7236056Z      at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
2023-08-30T17:35:02.7236496Z      at Sitecore.Update.Update.Serialization.SerializerFactory.GetSerializationType()
2023-08-30T17:35:02.7236834Z      at Sitecore.Update.Update.Serialization.SerializerFactory.GetSerializer()
2023-08-30T17:35:02.7237336Z      at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.PackageBuilder.PackageBuilder.GetSitecoreItemCommands(List`1 cmds, BuildContext ctx, String projectFileFolder, Project sourceTDSProject, HashSet`1 includedItems)
2023-08-30T17:35:02.7237860Z      at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.PackageBuilder.PackageBuilder.BuildPackage(BuildContext ctx)
2023-08-30T17:35:02.7238234Z      at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.PackageBuilder.Program.Main(String[] args)
2023-08-30T17:35:02.7238798Z   Inner Exception Could not load file or assembly 'Sitecore.Data.ResourceItems.ProtobufNet, Version=18.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.(System.IO.FileNotFoundException):
2023-08-30T17:35:02.7239352Z      at Sitecore.DependencyInjection.DefaultSitecoreServicesConfigurator..cctor()
2023-08-30T17:35:02.7443436Z ##[error]packages\HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.6.0.0.15\build\HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.targets(181,5): Error : The package builder failed. Please set the build logging level to Normal or Detailed and see the build output log for more information on the failure. 
2023-08-30T17:35:02.7445987Z F:\BuildAgent\agent\_work\1\s\packages\HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.6.0.0.15\build\HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.targets(181,5): error : The package builder failed. Please set the build logging level to Normal or Detailed and see the build output log for more information on the failure.  [F:\BuildAgent\agent\_work\1\s\Website.TDS.Deployment\Website.TDS.Deployment.scproj]
2023-08-30T17:35:02.7463158Z Done Building Project "F:\BuildAgent\agent\_work\1\s\Website.TDS.Deployment\Website.TDS.Deployment.scproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
2023-08-30T17:35:02.8669511Z Project "F:\BuildAgent\agent\_work\1\s\ATCCSitecore.sln" (1) is building "F:\BuildAgent\agent\_work\1\s\Site.ATCC.TDS.Content\Site.ATCC.TDS.Content.scproj" (22) on node 1 (default targets).
2023-08-30T17:35:02.8670152Z VerifyBuildProperties:
2023-08-30T17:35:02.8670361Z   TDSVersion: 6.0.0.15
2023-08-30T17:35:02.8670548Z   FrameworkVersion: 4
2023-08-30T17:35:02.8670746Z   TDS Target file version: 6.0.0.15
2023-08-30T17:35:02.8671109Z BeforeBuild:
2023-08-30T17:35:02.8671340Z   Visual Studio Version: 16.0
2023-08-30T17:35:02.8692132Z PrepareForBuild:
2023-08-30T17:35:02.8692374Z
```

Could some one please help me here.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, others had same issue as you have now:

https://andrewwburns.com/2022/07/13/sitecore-tds-could-not-find-assembly-sitecore-data-resourceitems-protobufnet-dll/

Fix was:

> To fix this I created a folder and dropped various required assemblies into it – including the 2 assemblies from Sitecore 10.2 – and then set the Sitecore Assembly Path setting (in the Update Package tab of the TDS project properties) to point to that folder.

Comment: getting below exception after following above article

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  The package builder failed. Please set the build logging level to Normal or Detailed and see the build output log for more information on the failure. Feature.Labels.TDS.Templates E:\GIT\packages\HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.6.0.0.15\build\HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.targets 181